# How big can a switch statement be?

Tags: swift, switch-statement

Recently I try to build a big switch statement, it has about 300 "case". I wonder if it's the best way to do that? and wanna know how big can a switch statement can be in swift?

```
var ln = [String: Any]()

switch sub{

    case 1:
        ln = ["a":["s":"fgee","t":"dhtr"], "b":"22", "c":"34","d":"12", "e":"922", "f":"3234"]
    case 2:
        ln = ["a":"289", "b":["s":"dgt","t":"bggh"], "c":"34","d":"2389", "e":"232", "f":"2234"]
    case 3:
        ln = ["a":"76454", "b":"254", "c":"94","d":"247", "e":"136", "f":"81"]  
    ...
    ...
    ...
    case 300:
        ln = ["a":"12", "b":"645", "c":"36","d":"15", "e":"587", "f":"565"]
    default:
        break
}
```

Thanks.

====== Edited =======

According to the comments, I rewrite the codes like below:

```
option[1] = ["a":["s":"fgee","t":"dhtr"], "b":"22", "c":"34","d":"12", "e":"922", "f":"3234"]
option[2] = ["a":"289", "b":["s":"dgt","t":"bggh"], "c":"34","d":"2389", "e":"232", "f":"2234"]
option[3] = ["a":"76454", "b":"254", "c":"94","d":"247", "e":"136", "f":"81"]  
...
...
...
option[300] = ["a":"12", "b":"645", "c":"36","d":"15", "e":"587", "f":"565"]
```

Comment: Why would you use a `switch` statement for that code? Just use an array of dictionaries to hold all of those possibilities. I'm assuming you have all 300 possible value. If not, use a dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: Were  there any specific issues with that big `switch` that you've encountered?

Comment: It is not advised to use the switch with 300 cases. You need to use some other control statement (ideally an algorithm) to achieve the same thing. I don't understand why you need a such switch statement.

Comment: Maddy's answer is extremely to the point. If your switch-statement is large enough to raise the question I would consider that a huge code-smell, and you should probably rethink what you're doing...